# SQL Server regular expression - grouping of charecters in square bracket

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, sql-server-2012

I am searching for a string in the table in the SQL Server database, for that I am creating a regular expression as I need to search with different combination.

```
select * from table where name like '%'+Sqlstring+'%'
```

Eg:->

and as an example `Sqlstring ="[sam12R]India",`

Here I don't want to take all characters individually (some of the characters I wanted to group and others individually also).

So my search string  will be like this

```
samIndia,
1India,
2India,
RIndia,
```

Comment: What flavor of SQL is this? MySQL? ProsgreSQL? MSSQL2005? 2008? Oracle? SQLite?

Comment: You can not query data like that in SQL Server. regular expression can only be used to the fullest once you enable CLR

Comment: depending on your exact requirements, it could be possible to achieve using Like and some logical operators: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859(v=sql.110).aspx